# Atmosphere WebSocketProtocol Broadcast

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I have a working jetty-based WebSocket server that I need to migrate to use Atmosphere.  I need to write incoming WebSockets messages to an internal queue for subsequent processing and the original message is returned o the client as positive acknowledgement of the transaction.

I've implemented using the WebSocketProtocol API of Atmosphere.  The connection gets brought up successfully and a single message is sent from the client to the server.  However, no response is received and it appears the connection gets closed.

Here are the log messages for the connection request:

```
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:08,222] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started application@1db9d253{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9090}
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:08,236] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started admin@6f5f892c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:08,237] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @15902ms
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:08,344] com.df.sensoringest.services.SensorIngestServiceIntegrationTest: Connecting to: ws://localhost:9090/dF/sensorIngest
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:14:46:08 +0000] "GET /dF/sensorIngest HTTP/1.1" 101 - "-" "-"  259
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:09,014] com.df.sensoringest.services.SensorIngestServiceIntegrationTest: Connected: WebSocketSession[websocket=JettyListenerEventDriver[com.df.sensoringest.services.SensorIngestServiceIntegrationTest$TestClient],behavior=CLIENT,connection=WebSocketClientConnection@79056e19{IDLE}{f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[CLIENT,validating],p=Parser@2b100b71[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null,p=WebSocketPolicy@6c4a33a4[behavior=CLIENT,maxTextMessageSize=65536,maxTextMessageBufferSize=32768,maxBinaryMessageSize=65536,maxBinaryMessageBufferSize=32768,asyncWriteTimeout=60000,idleTimeout=300000,inputBufferSize=4096]]},remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@432bf2ff[batching=true],incoming=JettyListenerEventDriver[com.df.sensoringest.services.SensorIngestServiceIntegrationTest$TestClient],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.WebSocketClientConnection]]
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:09,032] com.df.sensoringest.resources.socket.SocketResource: connection requested: 4c3b4254-a3bc-4a1f-900b-3b8ad9b9afc6
```

After the connection is established, I send a single message which is received by the WebSocket server:

```
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:16,015] com.df.sensoringest.services.SensorIngestServiceIntegrationTest: sending: This is a test message
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:16,035] com.df.sensoringest.resources.socket.SocketResource: received: This is a test message
INFO  [2015-05-19 14:46:16,352] com.df.sensoringest.resources.socket.SocketResource: connection closed: 4c3b4254-a3bc-4a1f-900b-3b8ad9b9afc6
```

The response is never received by the client and the connection gets closed.  There are no exceptions being thrown so I'm not sure what's going on.

Here is the WebSocket server code:

```
@Slf4j
@WebSocketProtocolService
public class SocketResource implements WebSocketProtocol {

  @Override
  public List<AtmosphereRequest> onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String data) {
    log.info("received: {}", data);
    webSocket.resource().getBroadcaster().broadcast(data);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public List<AtmosphereRequest>
      onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
    try {
      String bStr = new String(data, "UTF-8");
      log.info("received unexpected byte message: {}", bStr);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      log.error("unsupported text encoding: {}", e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AtmosphereConfig config) {
    log.info("config method called");
  }

  @Override
  public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
    log.info("connection requested: {}", webSocket.resource().uuid());
  }

  @Override
  public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket) {
    log.info("connection closed: {}", webSocket.resource().uuid());
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, WebSocketProcessor.WebSocketException t) {
    log.error("websocket error: {}", t.getMessage());
    log.error("status {}, message {}", t.response().getStatus(), t.response().getStatusMessage());
  }
}
```

and here is the test client:

```
  /**
   * The Test WebSockets Client
   */
  public static class TestClient extends WebSocketAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
      log.error("websocket session closed: {}, {}", statusCode, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
      log.info("Connected: {}", session);
      try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(5 * DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_SECOND));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("sleep interrupted ...", e);
      }

      try {
        log.info("sending: {}", sensorMessage);
        session.getRemote().sendString(sensorMessage);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error sending message: {}", e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
      log.info("unexpected websockets exception: {}", cause);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] payload, int offset, int len) {
      log.info("unexpected binary message received");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
      if (message != null) {
        response = message;
        log.info("websocket response received: {}", message);
      }
    }
  }
```

So, after all of this, what am I doing incorrectly or not doing to cause the connection to close and the broadcast back to the client to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting the broadcaster in my onOpen() method.  After doing this, and getting the broadcaster in my onMessage() method, I now get the response I was looking for in the client.

Here is the new socket resource code:

```
/**
 * Example resource to show integration of Atmosphere within Dropwizard.
 */
@Slf4j
@WebSocketProtocolService
public class SocketResource implements WebSocketProtocol {

  @Inject
  private BroadcasterFactory factory;

  private int requestCount = 1;

  @Override
  public List<AtmosphereRequest> onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String data) {
    Broadcaster b = webSocket.resource().getBroadcaster();
    b.broadcast(data);
    log.info("broadcaster: {}", b);
    log.info("received: {}", data);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public List<AtmosphereRequest>
      onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
    try {
      String bStr = new String(data, "UTF-8");
      log.info("received unexpected byte message: {}", bStr);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      log.error("unsupported text encoding: {}", e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AtmosphereConfig config) {
    log.info("config method called");
  }

  @Override
  public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
    log.info("connection requested: {}", webSocket.resource().uuid());
    webSocket.resource().setBroadcaster(factory.lookup("/sensorIngest/" +
        requestCount++, true)).suspend(-1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket) {
    log.info("connection closed: {}", webSocket.resource().uuid());
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(WebSocket webSocket, WebSocketProcessor.WebSocketException t) {
    log.error("websocket error: {}", t.getMessage());
    log.error("status {}, message {}", t.response().getStatus(), t.response().getStatusMessage());
  }
```

I am open to improvements as I'm really new to Atmosphere.  The one thing I have not figured out is how to send the server response to only one client.